# How do I create a unique child scope in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am having problem creating a child scope for each panel in an angularjs accordion.

The accordion is built up using data in this format:

```
$scope.accordionData = [
        {'partial': 'desktop-ui/partials/test1.html', 'args':{'key1': $scope.args.users,'key2': 'http://www.sungard.com'}},
        {'partial': 'desktop-ui/partials/test2.html', 'args':{'key1': $scope.args.contacts,'key2': 'http://financialsystems.sungard.com/solutions/asset-management'}}
];
```

The 2 objects in the array above contains

1. a partial for each panel and
2. an extra 'args' object that contains extra information that I want to use in the partial using interpolation like this {{args.key1}} or {{args.key2}}

In my Directive, I use this code to create a new scope for each panel:

```
// element is the accordion and panels is a jQuery list of panels for the accordion and dataList is the data 
function populatePanelsWithExtraArgs(element, dataList, panels) {               
   angular.forEach(dataList, function(data, index) { // for each panel         
      var dataArgs = data.args; // get the extra args
      var panel = panels[index]; // get each panel from the jQuery list
      panel = angular.element(panel); // convert to angular element
      var childScope = panel.scope(); // create a new scope HERE IS THE PROBLEM
      childScope.args = dataArgs; // add the args to each panel's scope.        
   });               
 }
```

The line 'panel.scope();' does not in fact create a new scope. The scope's id is the same as the main scope's id. Also, the first arg is overwritten by the second arg.

If I try this:

```
panel.scope().$new()
```

This works but then it adds 'args' to something called $$childTail (I'm using chrome debugger):

```
scope.$$childTail.args
```

Then this means that {{args.key1}} doesn't work anymore because the variable args is no longer on the main scope but on this $$childTail thing.

Comment: see [Understanding scopes in AngularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: @JoseM thanks I will have a read of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doThe solution to creating a new scope for each panel in the accordion was to compile the panel DOM element with its own directive, thus automatically creating a unique scope.

1. In the markup (in the Accordion Directive) I add a new class Directive panel-data:

   ```
   var panel = '<div class="accordion-body collapse in panel-data"><div class="sg-accordion-inner-wrapper"><div class="accordion-inner"></div></div></div>');
   ```
2. Then I created the new panelData Directive:

   ```
   angular.module('sgComponents').directive('panelData', [function () {
      return {
         restrict: 'C', // a class Directive
         scope: true // with its own unique scope
      };
   }]);
   ```
3. Then I used jQuery to select each 'accordion-inner' which is where the content goes:

   ```
   var innerElement = thisElement.find('.accordion-inner');
   ```
4. Next I got the scope of each one:

   ```
   var innerScope = innerElement.scope();
   ```
5. Then I called an utility function to add the content:

   ```
   var accordionConent = addContentToInclude(contentBuffer, content);
   ```
6. Then I compiled the accordionContent with the innerScope and appended it to the innerElement panel:

   ```
    innerElement.append($compile(angular.element(accordionContent))(innerScope));
   ```
7. Finally, when I came to add the extra arguments to the panel in the populateExtraArguments() function, all I had to do was get the panel, turn it into an angular element, get its scope (the panelData scope in fact) and then add the extra arguments to the scope:

   ```
   // element is the accordion and panels is a jQuery list of panels for the accordion        
   and dataList is the data 
   function populatePanelsWithExtraArgs(element, dataList, panels) {               
      angular.forEach(dataList, function(data, index) { // for each panel         
         var dataArgs = data.args; // get the extra args
         var panel = panels[index]; // get each panel from the jQuery list
         panel = angular.element(panel); // convert to angular element
         var childScope = panel.scope(); // get the scope
         childScope.args = dataArgs; // add the args to each panel's scope.        
     });
   ```

   }