# How to create a new isolated scope with an existing object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create a new scope with this object:

```
$scope.model = {
    itemA: "First item",
    itemB: "Second item"
};

// I know, this is wrong, but I want to show you, what I would like to do.
var newScope = $scope.$new($scope.model);
```

The new scope I want to access in the ngTransclude-Part of my directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

            transclude(scope.model, function (clone, scope) {
                element.find('section').html("").append(clone);
            });
```

And in the template:

```
<p>{{itemA}} - {{itemB}}
```

But this doesn´t work

I have the idea from: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/
but I don´t want to work in the scope of the directive, but in a new scope.

Answer (score 0):

his is my solution I found to a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760523/how-do-i-create-a-unique-child-scope-in-angularjs). Slightly long-winded but it works!

Create a new, 'empty' class directive with its own scope.

Add this directive as a class attribute to your DOM element. It automatically takes the scope of the new directive.

In your case, you would use it on your p tag. You would then select this element in your link function and call scope() on it:

```
1. <p id="ID" class="my-empty-directive">{{itemA}} - {{itemB}}

2. create your new directive:

   angular.module('sgComponents').directive('panelData', [function () {
      return {
         restrict: 'C', // a class Directive
         scope: true // with its own scope
      };
   }]);

2. link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

         var pTag = jQuery('#ID');     
         var angularElement = angular.element(pTag);
         var newScope = angularElement.scope(); // THIS WILL BE THE NEW EMPTY DIRECTIVE'S SCOPE
```

Comment: `scope: true` is not an isolated scope. It's a new scope which prototipically inherits from the parent scope. `scope: {}` is isolated. Also, you are not referencing the `link` function in the directive.

Comment: ps regarding referencing the link function, I don't need a link function because I will never create an instance of the directive. I just need its scope.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK when you are creating directive usually it inherits the scope. The idea is to create isolated scope and this is done by doing.

```
.directive('directiveName', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: "AE",
      scope:{
         yourModelName:"=";
      }
      link: function (scope, element) {
        var el = angular.element('<div>Here you put your template scope.yourModelName</div>');
        $compile(el)(scope);
        element.append(el);
      }
    };
  })
```

Will be copied from the upper scope but you can change it in the directive without changing it in the upper scope